# How to get file from a shared Google Drive link in Colab/Jupyter?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Without authenticating anything because it's a shared file, so you shouldn't need credentials.
Without manually adding the file to your shared folder or downloading it.
How does one read a file into a variable from a shared link directly?
Like this one:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HA3enF7c26JVm4ouGHBQ7v1_ToQ_pus9/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

(1) Try adjusting your link to become like below. That should allow your *"read a file into a variable"*...
(begins auto-download of file bytes).

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1HA3enF7c26JVm4ouGHBQ7v1_ToQ_pus9&export=download
```

(2) Your link is not testable at present (you need to change view settings to **Public**).
Maybe that's why the download fails (is seen as un-authorized access)?

[image]